# Mac OS X firewall rules to block UDP connection to an external server

Tags: mac, firewall

Can anybody help to recommand a firewall app for Mac OS X? I'm going to block UDP connection to an external server, and then I need to check whether it switch to TCP connection to the server automatically. I can do that on Windows Firewall Defender. But I haven't found any firewall app on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

MacOS has a firewall ported from OpenBSD — Pf. Although it's [not kept up to date](https://etcinsider.com/blog/2016/02/28/openbsd-pf-for-mac-os-x-is-mostly-outdated/) it still can be used for such a simple task you have.

Typically Pf isn't enabled by default, but ruleset crafted by Apple is loaded from `/etc/pf.conf`. It's not anything complex but rather a frame to be used later by some components of the OS.

For quick tinkering though you can simply load your own ruleset and enable Pf at the same time: `sudo pfctl -ef …filename…`

If you're looking for persistent solution instead, check out tutorials widely available on that subject all over the Internet.

Manuals are shipped with MacOS: `man pfctl`, `man pf.conf`